# ASP.net Entity Framework Code First custom initializer never called

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using EF Code First in an Asp.net project. Code First created my database just fine but I am having fits getting it to seed my database with data. I am using a custom database initializer like so:

```
namespace Toolkit.Model
{
    public class EntitiesContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ToolkitContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ToolkitContext context)
        {
            List<Server> Servers = new List<Server>
            {
                new Server { ServerName = "Server 16" },
                new Server { ServerName = "Server 29" }
            };

            foreach (Server server in Servers)
            {
                context.Servers.Add(server);
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I set the initializer in the the Global.asax.cs and force the database to initialize like so:

```
using Toolkit.Model;

namespace Toolkit
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new EntitiesContextInitializer());
            var context = new ToolkitContext();
            context.Database.Initialize(false);
        }

        ...
}
```

The problem is that my Initializer never gets called and so my database never gets populated. I have even tried changing the initializer to inherit DropCreateDatabaseAlways instead but still nothing... What am I missing here?

**EDIT**
So after dropping the database my initializer got called fine. However I still wonder why it didn't get called in other instances such as when I added a table (so the model changed) or when I changed the initialzer to be DropCreateDatabaseAlways.

Comment: Is your connection string correct? Are you able to save anything using that context?

Comment: @IronMan84 Yes I am connecting fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a similar configuration for a SQL CE database, but instead of DropCreate, I'm using CreateIfNotExists.
The difference between what I have and yours is that you have are creating a context and calling initialize on the database. Based on that, I would suggest that you remove the context setup and the Database.initialize calls that you have in the application_start method.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContextName>(new EntitiesContextInitializer)
```

in EF 5.0 the library is declared as

```
public static void SetInitializer<TContext>(IDatabaseInitializer<TContext> strategy) where TContext : DbContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Database Migrations with Code-First. Whenever you use Update-database command when your model changes, your Seed method (in Migrations) will be called.

This article explains more:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621

You can also force it in Application_Start() your way:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new EntitiesContextInitializer());
            var context = new ToolkitContext();
            context.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Comment: I am using database migrations. When I add the POCOs for a new table and do the update the table is created but the seed method is never called on my initializer. The only way I have gotten this to work is to manually drop the existing DB. As for the application start, if have already tried changing initialize to true with no success.

Comment: It is a actually the Seed method of DbMigrationsConfiguration<ToolkitContext> that is called when you do a migration, not the initializer. Example: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/31/seeding-membership-amp-roles-in-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx. Try placing your code there.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your overriden menthod, Seed, in class, EntitiesContextInitializer, place at the end of the method add a line:

base.Seed (context)